# bridged connection for windows 7 host and ubuntu guest in vmware player

Tags: windows-7, bridge, vmware-player

I installed ubuntu on my laptop in vmware player 5.0.0 build-812388) under windows 7.

I do coding in ubuntu and would like to connect to ubuntu remotely with ssh. From My understanding, I need to use Bridged connection.

NAT works. Bridged doesn't

How do I make it work?

seems basic but I couldn't find manuals for that.

Comment: This is off-topic. [SF] deals with production systems only, not development, test or toy systems. Please see the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.eightforums.com/virtualization/5137-how-add-virtual-network-editor-vmware-player.html

Check the above link, read from the beginning but vmware player 5.0 procedure is further below the post on the above link.

Instead of getting into all of the above and or vmware workstation 9.0, why don't you use virtualbox ?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html

It's free, very rich in features, extensive command-line. have never had any problems with it.

Just use bridged adapter in virtualbox, if you want to ssh from your local lan provided you had it configured on your ubuntu vm, that should work, if you want to allow it over the internet / external access then open the appropriate ssh port on your router and forward it to your vm ip address in bridged mode.

I would recommend using virtualbox instead of modifying vmware player 5.0, unless there is a specific feature of vmware which you want to utilize.

Hope this Helps

Comment: VB needs root privileges. I use synergy to use mouse and keyboard from another computer. i ran into some problems re-configuring synergy few years ago. I might give it a shot again.

Comment: VB Needs root privileges for ? Your host OS is windows 7, you can install it if you are the local admin of the machine. Just curious so I asked :-)

Comment: when i start vb from the start menu, it asks for root. so it needs root to start. by root i mean admin

Comment: Yes It would require elevated privileges once it is being installed but I haven't faced an issue with that. What are your concerns ? Just asking to understand as to why you are staying away from Virtualbox :-)

Comment: if a program uses higher privileges, I cannot control mouse and keyboard within this program. so I have no mouse or keyboard in virtual box. It's not that big of a deal, it would require just a couple hours of twikking of my settings and learning virtualbox. I also got used to vmware (the player is free). but once i have some time, i'll try to jump onto vb

Comment: In my case I'm using VMWare because that is what we have on the server and I'm prepping a VM to move there.